Adding jupyter key binding to configuration to docker setup
I am trying to add shortcut keys to jupyter configuration in my Dockerfile.
Using jupyter version 6, here is the relevant code snippet
FROM python:3.9
...

# jupyter
RUN pip install jupyter_server ipywidgets
RUN pip uninstall traitlets -y
RUN pip install traitlets==5.9.0
RUN pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions && \
  jupyter contrib nbextension install --user

RUN jupyter nbextension enable codefolding/main
RUN jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main
RUN jupyter nbextension enable scratchpad/main
RUN jupyter nbextension enable collapsible_headings/main
RUN jupyter nbextension enable highlight_selected_word/main

RUN mkdir -p ~/.jupyter
RUN echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '*' "             >  ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
RUN echo "c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False " >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
RUN echo "c.NotebookApp.token = '' "           >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

# **this does not work!**
RUN echo "c.NotebookApp.key_bindings = [ \n \
  { 'command': 'jupyter-notebook:move-cell-up',   'keys': ['Alt-Up'] }, \n \
  { 'command': 'jupyter-notebook:move-cell-down', 'keys': ['Alt-Down'] }]" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8890", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]


Jupyter is running fine with all extensions, the only problem is that the keybinding are not configured properly.
getting the error:
[W 07:18:00.438 NotebookApp] Config option `key_bindings` not recognized by `NotebookApp`.

